# Back to original border state when animation finished?

Tags: html, css

I use border animation for input when hover ! I can't set `border-width` in animation property so I set in `:hover` .When animation finished ,I want to go back to the original border state ,however border remain as `3px`! How to solve it ?

```css
 input {
   margin:1.2rem;
   padding:5px 10px;
 
 }
 .pp {
   margin:1.2rem;
   min-width:10px;
   height:10px;
 }
 input:hover {
   -webkit-animation-name: haha;
   -webkit-animation-duration:1s;
   outline:none;border-width:3px;
   animation-timing-function:ease-in-out;
   
 }
 @-webkit-keyframes haha {
    
    0% {
   
       border-left:solid red;
        opacity:.3;
      }
      20% {
       
        border-top:solid red;
        opacity:.7;
      }
      50% {
        
        border-right: solid red;
        opacity:.5;
      }
      70% {
          border-bottom: solid red;
      opacity:.9
      }
      100% {
        
      }
      
 }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>


<p><input type="text" ng-model="name"></p>
<p ng-bind="name" class='pp'></p>

<input type="text" ng-model="namelast">
<h3 ng-bind="namelast" class='pp'></h3>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Is this the same what you were expecting? please check

```css
input {
   margin:1.2rem;
   padding:5px 10px;
 
 }
 .pp {
   margin:1.2rem;
   min-width:10px;
   height:10px;
 }
 input:hover {
 border: 1px solid #ccc;
-webkit-animation-name: haha;
-webkit-animation-duration: 1s;
outline: none;
animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
   
 }
 @-webkit-keyframes haha {
    
    0% {
   
       border-left:solid red;
        opacity:.3;
      }
      20% {
       
        border-top:solid red;
        opacity:.7;
      }
      50% {
        
        border-right: solid red;
        opacity:.5;
      }
      70% {
          border-bottom: solid red;
      opacity:.9
      }
      100% {
      }
      
 }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>


<p><input type="text" ng-model="name"></p>
<p ng-bind="name" class='pp'></p>

<input type="text" ng-model="namelast">
<h3 ng-bind="namelast" class='pp'></h3>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I just added `border: 1px solid #ccc !important;` on `input:hover`

Comment: I don't want use `!important` as my coding standard . So can you edit answer without using that :)

Comment: @DavidJorHpan check now

Comment: So the problem is I can't set border width in animation without setting first in `:hover` !! Right

Comment: Thanks, dont forget to make it helpful and upvote it

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this just by removing the `border-width: 3px` from the hover effect. Try it in the snippet below.

```css
 input {
   margin:1.2rem;
   padding:5px 10px;
 
 }
 .pp {
   margin:1.2rem;
   min-width:10px;
   height:10px;
 }
 input:hover {
   -webkit-animation-name: haha;
   -webkit-animation-duration:1s;
   outline:none;
   border-width:1px;
   animation-timing-function:ease-in-out;
   
 }
 @-webkit-keyframes haha {
    
    0% {
   
       border-left:solid red;
        opacity:.3;
      }
      20% {
       
        border-top:solid red;
        opacity:.7;
      }
      50% {
        
        border-right: solid red;
        opacity:.5;
      }
      70% {
          border-bottom: solid red;
      opacity:.9
      }
      
 }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>


<p><input type="text" ng-model="name"></p>
<p ng-bind="name" class='pp'></p>

<input type="text" ng-model="namelast">
<h3 ng-bind="namelast" class='pp'></h3>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The CSS you are looking for is:

```
             animation-fill-mode: 
     -webkit-animation-fill-mode:
```

*The animation-fill-mode property specifies a style for the element when the animation is not playing (when it is finished, or when it has a delay).*

*By default, CSS animations do not affect the element until the first keyframe is "played", and then stops once the last keyframe has completed. The animation-fill-mode property can override this behavior.*

For more information:
https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_animation-fill-mode.asp